# Modulo division returning negative number

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, modulo

I am carrying out the following modulo division operations from within a C program:

(5^6) mod 23 = 8

(5^15) mod 23 = 19

I am using the following function, for convenience:

```
int mod_func(int p, int g, int x) {
    return ((int)pow((double)g, (double)x)) % p;
}
```

But the result of the operations when calling the function is incorrect:

```
mod_func(23, 5, 6) //returns 8
mod_func(23, 5, 15) //returns -6
```

Does the modulo operator have some limit on the size of the operands?

Comment: You are overflowing the `int` into a negative value. The modulus of a negative number will be negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5 to the power 15 is 30,517,578,125

The largest value you can store in an `int` is 2,147,483,647

You could use 64-bit integers, but beware you'll have precision issues when converting from `double` eventually.

From memory, there is a rule from number theory about the calculation you are doing that means you don't need to compute the full power expansion in order to determine the modulo result.  But I could be wrong.  Been too many years since I learned that stuff.

Ahh, here it is: [Modular Exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation)

Read that, and stop using `double` and `pow` =)

```
int mod_func(int p, int g, int x)
{
    int r = g;
    for( int i = 1; i < x; i++ ) {
        r = (r * g) % p;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: *The largest value you can store in an int is 2,147,483,647* -- *if* `int` is 32 bits, which is common but not universal.

Comment: I feel stupid for not thinking about the maximum integer size. All is well now - glad you brought up this method!

Answer (score 3):

The integral part of `pow(5,  15)` is not representable in an `int` (assuming the width of `int` is 32-bit). The conversion (from `double` to `int` in the cast expression) is undefined behavior in C and in C++.

To avoid undefined behavior, you should use `fmod` function to perform the floating point remainder operation.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the problem is 5 ^ 15 = 30517578125 which is greater than `INT_MAX` (2147483647). You are currently casting it to an `int`, which is what's failing.

Answer (score 0):

As has been said, your first problem in

```
int mod_func(int p, int g, int x) {
    return ((int)pow((double)g, (double)x)) % p;
}
```

is that `pow(g,x)` often exceeds the `int` range, and then you have undefined behaviour converting that result to `int`, and whatever the resulting `int` is, there is no reason to believe it has anything to do with the desired modulus.

The next problem is that the result of `pow(g,x)` as a `double` may not be exact. Unless `g` is a power of 2, the mathematical result cannot be exactly represented as a `double` for large enough exponents even if it is in range, but it could also happen if the mathematical result is exactly representable (depends on the implementation of `pow`).

If you do number-theoretic computations - and computing the residue of a power modulo an integer is one - you should only use integer types.

For the case at hand, you can use exponentiation by repeated squaring, computing the residue of all intermediate results. If the modulus `p` is small enough that `(p-1)*(p-1)` never overflows,

```
int mod_func(int p, int g, int x) {
    int aux = 1;
    g %= p;
    while(x > 0) {
        if (x % 2 == 1) {
            aux = (aux * g) % p;
        }
        g = (g * g) % p;
        x /= 2;
    }
    return aux;
}
```

does it. If `p` can be larger, you need to use a wider type for the calculations.